# How to exclude certain contents from being web scraped by Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape English questions with Python from a website (I already obtained the permission for doing this beforehand); I am using `BeautifulSoup`.

The English questions are nested between the tags `<div class="question_body">` and `</div>`. So below is my Python code that I wrote to extract all the English questions:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for p in range(1,10):
    web_page = requests.get('https://www.helpteaching.com/search/index.htm?grade=90&question_type=1&keyword=&entity=7&pageNum={}'.format(p))
   
    # Parse web_page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page.text, 'html.parser')
    
    # Create set of results based on HTML tags with desired data
    results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'question_body'})
```

But the simple code above is a bit problematic, as I do not want to web scrape anything that is a 'group questions'. The contents of 'group questions' (a set of different questions that are based on the same question texts) are also nested between the tags `<div class="question_body">` and `</div>`, but the difference between 'group question' and 'non-group question' is that the source html code for the 'group question' are preceded by:

```html
            <p class="group_instructions">
                This question is a part of a group with common instructions.
                <a style="text-decoration:underline;" href="/groups/4913/making-bread">View group &raquo;</a>
            </p>
```

for example, below is html source code for one of the group questions on the website:

```html
            <p class="group_instructions">
                This question is a part of a group with common instructions.
                <a style="text-decoration:underline;" href="/groups/4913/making-bread">View group &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        
        <div class="question_body">
            
            
        <a href="/questions/128621/which-is-not-an-ingredient-the-mother-put-in-the-bread">Which is NOT an ingredient the mother put in the bread?</a>
            <ol>

                    <li class="answer correct">
                        Sugar               
                    </li>

                    <li class="answer">
                        Salt    
                    </li>

                    <li class="answer">
                        Yeast
                    </li>

                    <li class="answer">
                        Flour    
                    </li>        
            </ol>              
        </div>
    </div>
```

Note how `<p class="group_instructions">` precedes `<div class="question_body">`.
The non-group questions are not preceded by the chunk that starts with `<p class="group_instructions">`.

Is there any way that I can exclude the group questions from being web scraped? I do not need to stick to BeautifulSoup, if this is necessary.

Thank you,

Comment: Use css and select the ones that follow a div: `div + .question_body`

Answer (score 0):

I think xpath will be easier to use if you have to parse node which does not contain certain tags. I have provided here the lxml solution if you are open to it.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import HTML

web_page = requests.get('https://www.helpteaching.com/search/index.htm?grade=90&question_type=1&keyword=&entity=7&pageNum=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page.text, 'html.parser')
tree = etree.fromstringlist(soup, parse=HTML)

#This will extract only questions without group questions node.****
results = etree.XPath('//div[@class="question"][not(.//p)]/div[@class="question_body"]/a/text()')

    for result in results:
        print(result)
```